# PowerAutomate Flow: Fails with TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, power-automate

I have a Power Automate Flow where a user submits a Microsoft Form and a work item is created in Azure DevOps. That is working fine.

Within forms, the user has to upload a file which is mandatory. I am trying to get the file in the work item as an attachment. For that, I am sending an HTTP PATCH request to Azure DevOps but I get TF400813 error even though I have access to the DevOps Board and I am able to attach a file in the work item manually.

Here is my flow:

[To create work item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5T7M.png)

[Attach files in that particular work item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPumH.png)

[This step is giving TF400813](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xOl.png)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Power Automate does not have access to your Azure DevOps.

Please go to the **Organization settings** -> **Security** -> **Policies** page to check if the “**Third-party application access via OAuth**” policy is turned off. If so, please **turn on** it and then try it again.

[image]

Comment: Oh. Got it. But I am curious to know, how can the flow create the work item when third-party application access is disabled?

Comment: Also, the first HTTP request is working fine. The second HTTP PATCH request is giving an error. Is there anything wrong with the body?

Comment: And I am trying this using two accounts. When I try it using my account with OAuth enabled, the flow is successful. With OAuth disabled, the flow gives an error in the "Create a work item" step.

Comment: No, I need to resolve it on my colleague's account. Can I update you tomorrow? Please help me if I still face the issue.

Comment: @shalpha Sure. Since it's calling the REST API in Power Automate, So, if the issue persists, please also try to call the same rest api [Add an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-an-attachment) in other Tools (e.g Postman) to check if it has the same issue.

Comment: Do I need to create PAT and pass it as header?

Comment: @shalpha In other tools (e.g Postman) you need to create PAT and pass it as header, however in Power Automate, it's not needed, Power Automate use connectors, OAuth used when creating an Azure DevOps connector in Power Automate.

Comment: Oh, got it. OAuth is enabled for the user but still getting the same error. HTTP Status Code: 401, TF400813. Is it something related to some other permissions?

Comment: @shalpha Seems to be a permission issue. Can you please share the full logs, also capture the screenshot of the error?